# Rank of a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be the vector space of all continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ on the field $\mathbb{R}$. What is the rank of the linear transformation 
$T:V\rightarrow V $ which was defined as below?
$$T(f(x))=\int_{0}^{1}(3x^3y-5x^4y^2)f(y)dy$$

Comment: Can you see an obvious upper bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T(f(x)) = $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}(3x^3y-5x^4y^2)f(y)dy\\
\displaystyle3x^3\int_{0}^{1}yf(y)\ dy-5x^4\int_0^1 y^2 f(y)\ dy$

$\int_{0}^{1}yf(y)\ dy$ is a constant as is $\int_0^1 y^2 f(y)\ dy$

So what does that say about $T(f(x))$?

Comment: thus we can conclude rank T=4?

Comment: @J.D No... for any $f, T(f)$ will be of the form  Ax^4 + Bx^3$  The rank of $T$ is $2.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $T(f)$ is a actually a polynomial...